# How to fix Array to String conversion Bootstrap PHP?

Tags: php, mysql, bootstrap-4

i want to call sidebar menu items from database, but when i put the items from database to the

which is i put in $menu, it returns error

```
        <?php 
            $a=0;
            foreach ($menu as $m ) {
                $data[$a]=$m->menu_name;
                // $menu .="<li class='active'><a href='#'><em class='fa fa-dashboard'>&nbsp;</em> ".$m->menu_name."</a></li>";
                $menu.="<li><a href ='#'>".$data[$a]."</a></li>";
                // echo $m->menu_name;
                $a++;
            }


        ?>


        <?php echo $menu; ?>
```

I dont know what's wrong, any help will appreciate. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Variable name conflict in your case. You have $menu variable which is an array then again you are assigning the menu li element to same variable. change variable name for li element like

```
<?php 
    $a=0;
    $menu1 = '';
    foreach ($menu as $m ) {
        $data[$a]=$m->menu_name;
        $menu1.="<li><a href ='#'>".$data[$a]."</a></li>";
       // $menu2.="<li><a href ='#'>".$m->menu_name;."</a></li>";
        $a++;
    }


?>


<?php echo $menu1; ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

IT help to convert your data in array to encode string.

Code:

```
$menu_title= json_encode($menu);
<?php echo $menu_title; ?>
```

Or

```
<?php 
echo implode("",$memu);
?>
```

Comment: It's supposed to be a string of HTML: `$menu.="<li><a href ='#'>".$data[$a]."</a></li>";` You don't need to encode that.